# WCF silently fails to deserialize list if item types don't match

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

With WCF, assume the following service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IForDataTypeA
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<DataTypeA> GetValues();
}

[DataContract]
public class DataTypeA { }
```

This is how it's defined on the server side (service host).

Now, someone - with no access to the server's source code - tries to use this WCF service. He defines the service interface himself but *accidentally* changes the name of the data type to `DataTypeB`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IForDataTypeA
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<DataTypeB> GetValues();
}

[DataContract]
public class DataTypeB { }
```

When he now calls `GetValues()` (via `ChannelFactory<IForDataTypeA>`) **the returned list will always be empty** but no exception is thrown.

Is there a way to make WCF throw an exception when the elements in the list can't be deserialized (instead of returning an empty list)?

---

Here's the complete code to reproduce the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace TestProj
{
    [DataContract]
    public class DataTypeA { }

    [DataContract]
    public class DataTypeB { }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IForDataTypeA
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<DataTypeA> GetValues();
    }

    [ServiceContract(Name = "IForDataTypeA")]
    public interface IForDataTypeB
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<DataTypeB> GetValues();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    internal class ServiceImpl : IForDataTypeA
    {
        public List<DataTypeA> GetValues()
        {
            return new List<DataTypeA>
            {
                new DataTypeA(),
                new DataTypeA(),
            };
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new ServiceImpl());
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            var endpointUrl = "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:5555/MyService";

            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IForDataTypeA), binding, endpointUrl);
            serviceHost.Open();

            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IForDataTypeB>(binding, endpointUrl);
            var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

            List<DataTypeB> values = channel.GetValues();
            // values will always be empty
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a versioning feature. It allows you to change the service definition without breaking callers. One day you'll be thankful for this. On the other hand your request is totally valid as a debugging aid.

Comment: Ideally Service interface should be shared with clients. What if you give Name to DataContract["Name="TypeA"] , tried this ?

Comment: @AjayKelkar Yes, this will work. (He could also rename the class.) But that's not the point. The point is that the developer changed the name *by mistake* but doesn't get any error from this.